# Getting error on running a multi-module project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-11, java-platform-module-system

I am making a maven project in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition 2020.2. It is a multi-module project. When I run a class from one of the module I get an error but it runs fine if I run from the packaged jar. Here is the Structure of application:

```
C:.
| pom.xml
|
+---DatabaseTier
|   |   pom.xml
|   |
|   +---src
|   |   \---main
|   |       +---java
|   |       |   |   module-info.java
|   |       |   |
|   |       |   \---org
|   |       |       \---Geek8080
|   |       |           |   DatabaseTest.java
|   |       |           |
|   |       |           \---service
|   |       |               \---database
|   |       |                   |   Database.java
|   |       |                   |
|   |       |                   \---entities
|   |       |                           JournalPage.java
|   |       |
|   |       \---resources
|   |               log4j2.xml
|   |               table.sql
|   |
|   \---target
|       +---classes
|       |   |   log4j2.xml
|       |   |   module-info.class
|       |   |   table.sql
|       |   |
|       |   \---org
|       |       \---Geek8080
|       |           |   DatabaseTest.class
|       |           |
|       |           \---service
|       |               \---database
|       |                   |   Database.class
|       |                   |
|       |                   \---entities
|       |                           JournalPage.class
|       |
|       \---generated-sources
|           \---annotations
\---Reports
    |   pom.xml
    |
    +---src
    |   +---main
    |   |   +---java
    |   |   |   |   module-info.java
    |   |   |   |
    |   |   |   \---org
    |   |   |       \---Geek8080
    |   |   |           |   ReportTest.java
    |   |   |           |
    |   |   |           \---service
    |   |   |               \---report
    |   |   |                       ExcelReports.java
    |   |   |                       PDFReports.java
    |   |   |
    |   |   \---resources
    |   |           log4j2.xml
    |   |           MTCORSVA.TTF
    |   |
    |   \---test
    |       \---java
    \---target
        +---classes
        |   |   log4j2.xml
        |   |   module-info.class
        |   |   MTCORSVA.TTF
        |   |
        |   \---org
        |       \---Geek8080
        |           |   ReportTest.class
        |           |
        |           \---service
        |               \---report
        |                       ExcelReports.class
        |                       PDFReports.class
        |
        \---generated-sources
            \---annotations
```

This is the main pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>org.Geek8080</groupId>
        <artifactId>Journal</artifactId>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <version>1.0</version>
    
        <modules>
            <module>DatabaseTier</module>
            <module>Reports</module>
        </modules>
    
        <name>Journal Daily</name>
    
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.3</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>11</source>
                        <target>11</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

The pom.xml in DatabaseTier module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>Journal</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.Geek8080</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>DatabaseTier</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.15.2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.Geek8080.DatabaseTest</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The pom.xml in Reports module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>Journal</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.Geek8080</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>Reports</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.Geek8080</groupId>
            <artifactId>DatabaseTier</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.Geek8080.ReportTest</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package org.Geek8080 in both
> module Reports and module DatabaseTier
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It speaks for itself pretty much

> *Package `org.Geek8080` in both module `Reports` and module `DatabaseTier`*

such that with the module system in place and explicit modules on the modulepath, no two modules can export the same package. This change was brought in the light of moving towards reliable configuration and better accessibility. More to read about those concepts could be found in [The State of the Module System](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/).

As a solution, you can rename the packages to `org.report.Geek8080` and `org.database.Geek8080` respectively in those modules.

Comment: Thanks for giving that documentation link, that was very helpful and I figured what was going wrong. The problem was that the main class in both modules were in same package i.e., org.Geek8080 and while building the application it was throwing the error. To fix it I changed the position of both main files in modules so that they are in different packages and it works fine now.

Comment: @PrashantPrakash Do take note, that if the `module-info.java` for both these modules exports that same package and they end up in the modulepath. It would still cause a "split package" issue at some point. Renaming the exported package would be the right way to deal with it.